Integer Solutions to $m^3+m^2+m=l^2$
I tried looking at the Problem modulo 4. Trivially one gets, that $m$ hast to be an even integer. After this step I do not see any further conclusion. Thank you in advance, it is a problem resulting from another problem which I could simplify into this form.

look at your title. Carefully

Thank you, figered out how to change the title. Should be correct now.

No Integer solutions except $(m,l)=(0,0)$ you can see it in LMFD, link : https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/48/a/5

what is $\gcd(m, m^2 + m + 1) $  for a nonzero integer $m  ; ; ? ; ; $

For nonzero $m$  we have $\gcd(m^2 + m + 1, m) = 1.$  For  $m$  we see $m^2 + m + 1 > 0$   so $m > 0$  to get a square. Thence both $m$ and $m^2 + m + 1$ are squares. Let $m = w^2,$  the demand is that $$ w^4 + w^2 + 1 $$ be a square  for integer $w > 0. $   This is problematic, as
$$ \left(w^2 \right)^2 <  w^4 + w^2 + 1 <  w^4 + 2 w^2 + 1 =   \left(w^2 +1 \right)^2 $$
Put briefly, the integer $w^4 + w^2 + 1$ lies strictly between consecutive squares, so is not itself a square.

FYI There wasn't a need to use $ m = w^2$, we already have $ m ^2  m^2 + m + 1 < (m+1)^2$.

+1 : Nice answer, which nails it, and avoids tangling with the rational root theorem.

@CalvinLin:  does your comment have a typo?   Did you mean $m^2$ where you typed $m^2m^2$?

@J.W.Tanner I meant $m^2 < m^2 + m + 1 < (m+1)^2$.
